# How to get Columns(Fields) in a List in Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get the columns(Fields) of a List in a Sharepoint Site so that I can present the appropriate fields to the user for Create and Update Actions on ListItems. It's mentioned in the Documentation that a List will have a property called "fields" which will contain these columns. However, these are not returned by the API. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

`/items?expand=fields(select%3DTitle,FullName)`

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the query parameter ?select=fields to get the field list.

Eg. **GET** `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}?select=fields`